# Typescript - How to extract the objects inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Here is the `variants` array:

```
[
  {
    type: 'color',
    options: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
  },
  {
    type: 'size',
    options: ['M', 'G', 'GG']
  }
]
```

Firstly, I need to get an array of `type` like this `types = ['color', 'size']`. Then, I'll use this array inside a `mat-select`:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Types" (selectionChange)="typeChange($event.value)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type"> {{type}} </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Secondly, I need to populate a array of `options` by filtering the `variants` array to find the correct type:

```
typeChange(type: string) {
  const variant = this.variants.find(v => v.type === type);
  this.options = variant.options;
}
```

Then I can populate the second `select` with the options:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Options">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt"> {{opt}} </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I need to populate this two `mat-selects` using `variants` array. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Actually, I have showed it in the answer. I'm not sure how this bad feedback helps anyone.

Comment: I thought it was answering homework as well based on the phrasing, but I don't think so - it seems like James is thinking in terms of his requirements and passing along extraneous details in the event we can validate some of those assumptions as to what he's done, but the tone sounds like he's following a recipe, or a homework assignment.  If you switch out the phrasing 'need', 'will', 'can' for the words 'want'/'want to','should be able to because' this question would read better. I don't think it's hw, but there is something to Mrchief 's reaction to the phrasing here that's valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong, I believe instead of two arrays of variants, there is one array.
I have created a sample example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focbfn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).
You just have to create types array.

Here is the ts code :

```js
 variants = [
  {
    type: 'color',
    options: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
  },
   {
    type: 'size',
    options: ['M', 'G', 'GG']
  }
]
types = [];
options = [];
ngOnInit(){
this.variants.forEach(t=>this.types.push(t.type));
}
typeChange(type: string) {
  const variant = this.variants.find(v => v.type === type);
  this.options = variant.options;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: hey one last question... what if I have an array of arrays `File[][] [ [file, file, file], [file, file] ]` that is ordered by type 'color' options (same order)?

Comment: can you please share that json on provided link of stackblitz, It will be good for me to answer your comment.

Comment: Please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3uapxf?file=src/app/app.component.ts and let me know if you need any help in this.

Comment: can you move the filenames to `options: [
        {
          option: 'red',
          // [filename1, filename2]
          filenames: ''
        }` ?

Comment: every array needs to be positioned in the right object (same order of option)

Comment: check on stackblitz

Comment: Nice... Thank you for the help once again!